# Rand Ints cannot be resolved when used in a function

Tags: java

Everything is fine except when I define product as the two random ints multiplied, I get unresolved variable. Works if the ints are regular inputs but for some reason using random ones for the product doesnt work.  Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class class3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random rn1 = new Random();
        int product;

        int answer;

        for(int i =0; i < 1; i++) {
            int answer1 = rn1.nextInt(9) + 1;
            System.out.println(answer1);
        }

        Random rn2 = new Random();

        for(int i =0; i < 1; i++) {
            int answer2 = rn2.nextInt(9) + 1;
            System.out.println(answer2);
        }

        product = answer1 * answer2;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("What is the product of these numbers?");

            answer = scan.nextInt();

            if(answer == product) {

                System.out.println("yay");
            }


            if(answer != product) {

                System.out.println("no");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to sort out the formatting of your code first

Comment: `int answer2` is declared inside the `for` loop.  It is limited in scope to inside the `for` loop - you know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with random numbers. The problem is that you initialize `answer1` and `answer2` inside a loop. If you initialize a variable inside of the loop it doesn't exist outside of the loop. Try adding

```
int answer1 = 0;
int answer2 = 0;
```

before the loops. Also your loops only iterate one time. Why have a loop that only iterates once? You also don't need two random objects. Try instead:

```
   answer1 = rn1.nextInt(9) + 1;
   System.out.println(answer1);

   answer2 = rn1.nextInt(9) + 1;
   System.out.println(answer2);

   product = answer1 * answer2;
```

Comment: Why have *two* `Random` objects? Why even bother having these meaningless `for` loops?